# slideUp function in jquery not working

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Unable to figure out why slide-up function in `JQUERY` is not working, when I click on remove button.

You can see my code from [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4o3LLvo1/)

Comment: Where is the `$.slideUp()` code? I don't see it anywhere.

Comment: In the js file.It is flow.slideUp(900) on line 57

Comment: That isn't in your fiddle. And if you can, you should include your code in the SO post and not just link to a 3rd party site like jsfiddle. Please read this and give us a complete, minimal, verifiable example of the problem http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @MichaelCoker is being too gentle....your code needs to be posted in the question as questions should be self contained. We shouldn't have to go off site to review your issue. Demos are great but only to support what actually exists in the question itself

Comment: I have included the jquery script file.The slideDown function is working perfectly but not the slideUp

Comment: Thanks for the info I will update the question.